# Configuration Form Access Denied

Tags: users, 8, routes

I am porting a module to Drupal 8. I have correctly setup the path in routing.yml but it always says access denied even I am logged in with user 1.

routing.yml

```
flood_control.flood_control_config_form:
  path: '/admin/config/flood-control'
  defaults:
    _form: '\Drupal\flood_control\Form\SettingsForm'
    _title: Flood Control
  requirement:
    _permission: 'administer site configuration'
```

.links.menu.yml

```
flood_control.flood_control_config_link:
  title: Configure Flood Control
  description: 'Configuration Form for flood control'
  parent: system.admin_config
  route_name: flood_control.flood_control_config_form
```

What am I missing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can be just a typo, look at requirement, you missed a 's'.

```
  requirements:
    _permission: 'administer site configuration'
```

Look at [here](https://www.drupal.org/node/2166447) for a complete skeleton. (or a collection of modules examples [here](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/examples/))